BeautifulSoup4 403
i'm truing get soup from url
https://www.fc-moto.de/epages/fcm.sf/ru_RU/?ObjectPath=/Shops/10207048/Products/Bogotto-Losail-Ladies-2PC-Leathersuit/SubProducts/Bogotto-Losail-Ladies-2PC-Leathersuit-0007
but get 403
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import requests

url = "https://www.fc-moto.de/epages/fcm.sf/ru_RU/?ObjectPath=/Shops/10207048/Products/Bogotto-Losail-Ladies-2PC-Leathersuit/SubProducts/Bogotto-Losail-Ladies-2PC-Leathersuit-0007"
UserAgent().chrome

req = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': UserAgent().chrome})
print(req.response)
for key, value in req.request.headers.items():
  print(key+": "+value)

<Response [403]>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: /
Connection: keep-alive
on local machine it's work, but when i start on VM Ubuntu 20.4 on virtual hosting result 403 ((

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I tried your code and run without errors. The status code was 200 OK. Maybe, your problem is a block in the network.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import requests

url = "https://www.fc-moto.de/epages/fcm.sf/ru_RU/? 
ObjectPath=/Shops/10207048/Products/Bogotto-Losail-Ladies-2PC- 
Leathersuit/SubProducts/Bogotto-Losail-Ladies-2PC-Leathersuit-0007"
UserAgent().chrome

req = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': UserAgent().chrome})
print(req.status_code)
for key, value in req.request.headers.items():
   print(key+": "+value)

Terminal:

200


User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)


AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36


Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br


Accept: /


Connection: keep-alive


Please don't post an answer just to say you can't reproduce the problem: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277924/13138364

yeap on local machine it's work, but when i start on VM Ubuntu 20.4 on virtual hosting result 403 ((

@Еремеев Евгений you should add that information in your question, it could be relevant to fix the issue
